# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when using json API result and NSDictionary

Tags: json, macos, api, swift

I am trying to use an API to get json data every 0.5 seconds. The API allows thousands of requests per second however sometimes when running the application, I get this crash:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This is the code I am using to get the json data.

```
    var url : String = "URL.COM" 
    var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest

    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
        let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as NSDictionary
```

Can anyone advise me how to prevent this? I understand why the data might be nil occasionally but I want the program to keep checking regardless of if it is nil or not, as it will soon be something other than nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this, before the sterilization:

```
if data == nil 
{
   println("data is nil")
   return
}
```

Comment: Though this solves the error but @Diego Freniche 's answer is more in the spirit of Swift.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lays in data. It can be `nil`, but you're unwrapping it using !, which means: "I know there's some data inside here, unwrap it". The problem is when there's no data.

To solve it, use this pattern in Swift:

```swift
if let myData = data {
// do something using myData. If data is nil, doen't even enter here
}
```

Complete code:

```swift
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
    if let myData = data {

    let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(myData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as NSDictionary
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it makes complete sense. Only issue is now I cant refer to jsonResult here  `let id = jsonResult["ip"] as AnyObject? as? String`

Comment: Converting `NSData` into Swift `Dictionary` is a painful process. I suggest you to use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: This one is better answer, just jsonResult should also be put in 'if let' as JSONObjectWithData() may also return nil.

Comment: @abdullah: you're right. But once showed the basics of this mechanism, it's just a matter of iterate :-D

Comment: There is no need to create a second var. if let data = data { ... }